# Push view controller flip transition doesn't include navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am pushing a view controller whilst animating it so it flips. However, the animation is only applied to the view beneath the navigation bar, so the navigation bar hides for a few seconds then suddenly appears again. How can I apply the animation to the entire view, including the navigation bar?

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"OverviewiPad" bundle:nil];
OverviewViewController *overviewVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverviewViewController"];
overviewVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:overviewVC animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```